# Can't invoke a function in the child iframe by parent via postMessage() - cross origin

Tags: javascript, iframe, cors, postmessage

I cannot get this CORS workaround to work in Chrome 52.0. My iframe and parent page are on different subdomains.

My iframe's event listener:

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
       //doesn't log it
       console.log('message');
       if(event.data === "invokeChildFunction()") {
           childFunction();
       }
    });
    function childFunction() {
        alert('Parent frame just invoked my function')
    }
}
```

The parent frame:

```
var iframeWindow = $('iframe').contentWindow;
var invokeChildFunction = function () {
  iframeWindow.postMessage("invokeChildFunction()", "https://mansion-assessment-sdimoff.c9users.io/CORS/index.html");
}
```

`invokeChildFunction()` doesn't log anything at the iframe's page

Comment: What is purpose of assigning `window` to `iframe` at `var window = $('iframe').contentWindow;`?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm trying to reference the iframe window. How else should I go about that?

Comment: Would try an identifier other than `window` to avoid confusion. Do `window`'s have different origins?

Comment: Okay, I'll change it to `iframe`. That doesn't solve the problem, though. It works when I send from the child. Yes, this should be able to work in cross-domain

Answer (score 4):

You should try using

In parent frame:

```
var iframe = $('iframe')[0];
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('invokeChildFunction', iframe.contentWindow.location);
```

In child/iframe:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
  if (event.data === 'invokeChildFunction') {
    // do whatever you want to
  }
})
```

What you did wrong was selecting elements with tag-name, on selecting elements with tag name you get an array of elements so you need to reference them as array.

Also use some validation to validate the source of events.

Comment: Will this even work if, as OP states, My iframe and parent page are on different subdomains.

Comment: Yes window.postMessage can be used to communicate between pages on different sub-domains. You could [check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for further clarification.